# What I need for a successful GET request using retrofit android?

Tags: android, authentication, client-server, retrofit2

I'm trying to create my own application like an e-mail client. I use Retrofit library and I have already managed to create POST request for authorization via username and password. Maybe somebody can help me with structurising my general task(which classes I have to create or smth like that) because I can't create the strategy of its development. I'm a beginner in android development and also in retrofit library. When I first had made a POST request it was like a surprise because I didn't understand how it worked. So maybe somebody can advise me some tutorials or can explain from what I have to start for having s really successful GET request. I have some previous questions right here: [Adding authorization header interface android retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494665/adding-authorization-header-interface-android-retrofit/51494977#51494977). After some conversations with more professional developers, I have realized that I don't know where I have to begin. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're question is too broad. Share your code & specify exactly what you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think This Tutorial is Good for you -> [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)